# Visual Studio Community 2013 - automatically close an open tag

Tags: visual-studio-2013

Visual studio will create the closing tag when you create the opening one..this works great when you are going linearly..open tag create contents..closing tag is already there.

Its less useful when you are cutting and pasting and moving etc.

Dreamweaver will auto close an open tag when you type < /. Is there such an option in Visual Studio..?

Thanks

Comment: If I have an open tag in the VS2013 HTML source editor and I type `<` it suggests the closing tag for me. Do you not see that behaviour?

Comment: I've just reset my settings and yes now I do! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just typing the opening angle bracket < will prompt the auto suggest that will have the closing tag at the top.

If you type < / then the closing tag should be the only suggestion and you can just hit return to use it.